# Failed to connect to Websphere MQ Manager

Tags: ibm-mq

Whenever I connect to a Queue Manager on my Websphere MQ, I get the following error:

```
An unexpected error(2495) has occurred. (AMQ4999)
```

The details of this error message says:

```
An unexpected error (insert_0) has occurred.
```

I have no idea what this means as I'm new to this. I tried to restart my Websphere MQ as well as the IBM MQSeries server but this still persists. I even tried to create a difference MQ Manager but it still persists. Do you have any idea as to what causes this issue?

Comment: You would need to provide some more details.  What type of application is this, for example, C, .Net, MQ Classes for Java, MQ Classes for JMS?  2495 is a very generic catch all error that is produced when an error was not expected.  It would be helpful if you could provide a minimal example of code that causes the error.  What version of MQ client are you using, what version of MQ server is being connected to.  Have you looked at the  queue managers AMQERR01.LOG at the time of the error to see if anything is logged?  Check in the /var/mqm/errors for any fresh AMQERR01.LOG entries or FDC files.

Comment: Given the AMQ4999 error, I assume the application in question is MQ Explorer? Can you confirm?

Comment: Bit of searching suggests this might be your problem even though the error message number isn't the one you saw (you saw the MQ Explorer catch all message). http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21413508